# Unable to find package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design. No packages exist with this id in source(s):

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, visual-studio-2017, razorengine

I am trying to learn .Net Core. For that i am creating an empty project in Visual Studio 2017. When i tried to Build Project the following error appears

> Unable to find package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design. No packages
>   exist with this id in source(s)

Also Yellow Caution Sign is showing with Project Dependencies

Comment: What is your .net core version? Could you find the package in your dependencies? Have you tried to restart visual studio and reopen the project?

Comment: .net core Version is 2.1. Yes it is there but yellow caution sign is there with it. and Yes i tried Both of your suggestion but error still there

Answer (score 0):

Check your package sources in Visual Studio under Tools > Options > NuGet Package Manager > Package Sources. There should be a reference to "nuget.org" in there:

[image]